# How to enable auto login in TTY while getting softwares like tmux work?

Tags: login, tty

Currently i'm using flow redirect to enable auto login mode , but when i launch `tmux` in tty1 , it stuck.

`c1:12345:respawn:/bin/login -f USERNAME</dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1`

Is there any better solution for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the redirections are not enough to have `/dev/tty1` be considered as the controlling terminal for the `login` session.

Why not to use the `-a` (autologin) option from `agetty`? Example:

```
c1:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -a USERNAME 38400 tty1 linux
```